# gif loader centered as top layer

Tags: php, javascript, progress-bar, loader, gif

I have a php form. After this form is submitted, if all data is valid, then it executes a python script which takes 5-10 seconds. For this wait period I would like to have a progress bar (.gif) displaying in the middle of the screen. If I could also 'fade away' the background so that the progress bar was like a top layer and the background a back layer, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the question? you expect us to write the code for you ?

Comment: @RageZ - use your imagination. I figured he's asking for some pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any javascript libraries, such as jQuery? In any of the libraries, I'd imagine there'd be a dozen or so lightbox plugins floating about. Even if you don't want to use a library, you can take a look at their code, and instead of displaying a DIV, just display your gif, if you know what I mean.

There are even some plugins built specifically for this purpose, such as the [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin for jQuery.

---

The basic algorithm for doing what you want goes like this:

1. Start Ajax Request
2. Display semi-transparent dark image over the whole page, with an animated gif in the middle.
3. Listen for Ajax response
4. Remove the overlay and loader gif.

I assume you already have steps 1 and 3 going alright. Step 4 is easy-peasy. Step 2 however isn't as easy, but still shouldn't be too hard. I couldn't tell you the code to do it myself, since I've just used lightbox plugins in the past. Take a look on Google for "simple lightbox" or something like that, since all you really want is the most basic functionality.  This blog post talks about [a CSS-only lightbox](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/) which would be a good starting point to help you style the overlay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I am not familiar at all with Ajax... (shame on me). Therefore, I haven't 1 and 3 done. All I have done is the .gif I would like to use. I skimmed trough w3schools tutorial on Ajax, but didn't understand most of it. If you, or anybody else, could explained how I can use Ajax for this particular case, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I have already looked into that. but thanks for your help anyway.